# Support "two account" login when implementing IProfileService

Tags: identityserver4

We are attempting to integrate IdentityServer4 in facilities where we want to combine two login accounts (not 2FA in the traditional sense). Users would be pre-logged-in to Windows "service" accounts on computers fixed to a physical location in the building. They would be auto-authenticated to IS4 with the service account per [IS4 Windows Authentication](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/topics/windows.html). Then, users would logon with their personal Active Directory credentials in the web app form (like the IS4 quickstart logon form). This would provide us the ability to grant more granular permissions based on the identity and location of the user.

We are trying to implement [`IProfileService`](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/profileservice.html) to call an internal API that expects both account IDs. The claims we issue from the response of that internal API in `GetProfileDataAsync()` should be a result of the overlapping permissions of the two accounts. `IsUserActiveAsync()` should validate that both the service account and the user account are active.

How can we gain access to both account IDs from within our implementation of `IProfileService`? The sub-parameter of type `ClaimsPrincipal` passed to the `IProfileService` methods seems to only support a single account. Is this type of environment supported by IS4 out-of-the-box, or would this require some customization?

Comment: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/federation_gateway.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution we landed on was modifying the login flow to perform a transparent Windows authentication immediately followed by a username/password authentication. We cached the username for the Windows authentication in a custom claim during the username/password authentication so that both the service account and the user account would be accessible in the `Principal` in `IProfileService`.

Answer (score 1):

These are just assumptions, but it looks to me that the service account is in fact not a real user account but rather the account for the computer. So it doesn't actually identify a user but a computer. And from what you write it seems that it is only the location that matters.

I think that [extension grants](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html) may be the answer in your case. Because you can create your custom login for machine/user. Combining the information in one access token.

The alternative may be to look at ip address. But this only works when the computer has a fixed and known ip address.

Both options will bind the user to the location.

The permissions should not be part of the setup in order to keep the access token small, though IdentityServer has the structure to do so. Instead you may want to look at an authorization server (like the [PolicyServer](https://leastprivilege.com/2018/01/17/announcing-policyserver/)) that handles the permissions. In that case you can use the Windows username of the machine (if verified and part of the token) or the ip address and also the user id to get the permissions for the user for that location.