# Pass extra information to IProfileService

Tags: identityserver4

When implementing IS4, we want to have a couple of extra fields on the `/Account/Login` form (we're building off of the Quickstart UI). The data provided by these fields (location info - 1) building and 2) station within the building) needs to be accessible when `IProfileService` is called as they are pieces of information used to determine the claims to be provided in `GetProfileDataAsync()`. We tried storing the data in `HttpContext.Items`, but that data is lost since there is a redirect that occurs before `IProfileService` is called.

Do you have any recommendations for how to pass this data back to `IProfileService`?

Comment: Like what kind of field and extra info are you talking about?

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius, I just updated the question. Basically, some location info which is tied to the physical stationary machine on which the user is logging in.

Comment: And is that user specific information? Reason I am asking is because what you are building seems extremely fragile because even if you could achieve this you would forfeit any sort of cookie based authentication or single sign on or external provider because of the direct dependency to have these fields in the login form?

Comment: Hmm, you may be right. It's not user-specific info, but we want to issue claims based on identity as well as location (related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54241253/support-two-account-login-when-implementing-iprofileservice)). This is my first go at working with auth and IdentityServer, so I'm still wrapping my head around it.

Comment: And the user is able to specify that information freely or is that determine programatically? And does it change for a user?

Comment: In the Production environment, generally no. These will be hidden fields and data set by the currently logged in Windows AD account (which is tied to the physical location in the building, not the specific user). In development and maybe on some admin/manager machines, they may be able to select the values to simulate being in different physical locations.

Comment: So the AD can provide the info to get the required claims - that is certainly achievable. For development and your admin machines, you could something like mock implementation of your AD abstraction layer. But most definitely would not recommend anything like what you are attempting to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the extension methods on the HttpContext, SignInAsync, allows you to pass in any extra login related claims. If you add ‘building’ and ‘building_station’ as claims when you call SignInAsync from the AccountController, you should be able to access it through the HttpContext.

To do this you need to add the HttpContextAccessor to the IProfileService implementation through dependency injection, and once you get the HttpContext from it you should be be able to locate the appropriate claims in HttpContext.User.

Comment: Aha! Duh. Stuffing them it `HttpContext.Items` is very temporary (scoped to single request). But, persisting them as custom claims keeps the data around. This seems to be working. Thanks!